# How to refactor sql query in a foreach

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code that works:

```
foreach (var r in rlist)
    {
        if (r.IndexOf("_") != -1)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(r.Split('_')[1]);
            var x_tmp = (from x in db.tblX where x.x_id == my_id && x.x_id == id select x).First();
            x_tmp.order = someNumber;
        }
     }
     db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a way to refactor this?

Comment: Is it supposed to set the same order for all the items? Shouldn't you be incrementing the order?

Comment: -1: also, why are you comparing `x.x_id` to both `my_id` and `id`? **Does this code compile? Does it work as intended?** Did you try to improve it by yourself before putting it on our collective table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you are calling the query a few times with `id`, so let's just call it only once with all of them.

```
(from x in db.tblX where x.x_id == my_id && ids.Contains(x.x_id) select x)
```

There you go, now `IEnumerable`'s `Contains` function allows you to look up the id in a list of `ids` you have made in advance. I usually prefer to use LINQ methods, as simple LINQ expressions tend to be more complex than they should be:

```
db.tblX.Where(x => x.x_id == my_id && ids.Contains(x.x_id))
```

We can now use a plain `foreach` as suggested in comments, such that we don't have side effects:

```
var ids = rlist.Where(x => x.IndexOf("_") != -1).Select(x => int.Parse(x.Split('_')[1]));

var items = db.tblX.Where(x => x.x_id == my_id && ids.Contains(x.x_id));

foreach (var item in items)
    item.order = someNumber;

db.SaveChanges();
```

Done.

Comment: Why are you suggesting `ForEach()`? I think `foreach` is more idiomatic and readable. [And `ForEach()` also clashes with the idea of side-effects-free lambdas, that's behind LINQ.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) Also, your first `ForEach()` doesn't work, you want to use `Select()` there.

Comment: Adapted answer to your feedback, thanks! Seems I need to think some more about avoiding side effects...